pgadmin connection to server error
I'm having a server-connection-error on pgadmin dashboard. I kept having a connection timeout error after prompting me to enter the password for user "postgres" after clicking on PostgreSQL 16:
Please enter the password for user 'postgres' to connect to the server - "POSGRESQL 16".
I've tried entering the password I used for the first installation but I kept seeing the same prompt.
During the installation of postgres, it says postgres will be saved in the already existing data directory. After going through the installation, I tried to remove the data directory and then initialized it using initdb hoping this would fix the server-connection error but it remains the same.
What can I do in this situation?

You would have to investigate the cause, starting with figuring out if the server is running or not. Your description is too vague to guess an answer without actually looking at your system. Even the most basic information is missing, like the operating system you are using, the exact way you installed PostgreSQL, what was there before etc.
